# How to setup linting rules for functions calls without brackets ()

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

Coming from java, I've spent many a day debugging what almost inevitably could be summed up as the compiler/linter not warning of function calls made without the brackets.

i.e with a class as such:

```
export class democlass {

function demofunction(){

    }
}
```

Very often, in TS/js, on calling demofunction from another class, I'll do this

```
instanceOfDemoClass.demofunction
```

instead of

```
instanceOfDemoClass.demofunction();
```

Obviously, in java, the compiler will immediately scream at you, a behaviour which Ts/VScode doesn't exactly emulate.

I'd like to setup a rule to warn about this call if, of course, the called class doesn't contain a property named "demofunction".

Any help/experience with this problem?

Cheers

Comment: You're probably looking for https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions or https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unused-expressions/

Comment: For the most part typescript helps a lot here. If you don't execute a function, then it returns that function. And as soon as you try to use that value anywhere, typescript will know it's a function rather than some other value and you'll get type errors everything. The eslint @Bergi mentions will snag unuexecuted side effect only functions, but that doesn't really solve the `const foo = fetchSomeValue // oops` case, though. But like I said, typescript has you back there.

Comment: TypeScript has a feature named [uncalled function checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#uncalled-function-checks) that may help under some constraints. Most notably, one has to use the option [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks)